# Manytomany django using existing key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I hope this is not a duplicate question. I am trying to setup models in django.
In model 1 I have one kind items (parts), these can together form item type 2 (car).
I get the prices for all of these from outside interface to a model prices.
How can I setup the relationship between price - > part and price  - > car.
I do not know when I get the prices if the ident belongs to car och part.

```
class parts(models.Model):
   ident = models.CharField("IDENT", max_length = 12, unique = True, primary_key = True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class car(models.Model):

   ident = models.CharField("IDENT", max_length = 12, unique = True)    
   start_date = models.DateField()
   end_date = models.DateField()
   parts= models.ManyToManyField(parts)    



class Prices(models.Model):
    ident= models.CharField(max_length=12)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places= 4)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ident

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (("ident", "date"),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine you would not store price in your model since you need this to be 100% real time.  So you have;

*car models.py*

```
from parts.models import parts

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
parts = models.ManyToManyField(parts)
```

Hopefully you're not trying to develop like a full scale autozone type deal, but if it's simply a car model object that is comprised of many parts than this is the basic setup you would want.  having the many to many relationship to parts allows one car to have many parts.  parts can belong to many cars.  You don't have to specify a manytomany relationship in the parts model as the two way communication will already be handled in your cars model.

As far as price is concerned you could have a price database field in your parts model, but once again if this needs to be real time, you probably want to request that price via an api and display it directly in your webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was having issues with the other join, and made a typo in my question. It is exactly the issue of joining 2 datasets (2 django models) without having to setup key. I have now done it by sql join in a .raw query instead. I was wondering if there was a built in way to do this. Thanks again for your quick reply.

Comment: sorry not understanding the question, are you asking how to query multiple models into one queryset? something like 

from itertools import chain
report = chain(car, parts)

Comment: Yesm that is my question. The ident is unique key between tables, and I need to just join the price onto parts or car with a "WHERE" clause. I now solved it with a .raw on the queryset on parts. IS there a better way?